# FFmpeg PNG frame extraction isn't actually lossless

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

**EDIT: It turned out this wasn't an FFmpeg-related issue. The culprit was VLC which didn't show me the video accurately. In particular, VLC has some sort of enhancement filter that only engages itself when the video is resized such as using the Always Fit Window option. This filter had the effect of removing the banding artifacts that were actually present all along in the original file.**

One would reasonably expect that using FFmpeg to extract the frames of a video as individual PNG files would yield lossless results.
I have recently discovered to my horror that this is not the case. The extracted frames have very noticeable banding artifacts, not present in the original video.
I've tried many different versions of ffmpeg, old and new, yet this issue seems to always occur.

I attach here a sample video I made that contains a simple looping gradient that doesn't have any artifacts I can see. I suggest to use VLC to view the video as all other players I tried such as ffplay and MPC-HC will render it with noticeable artifacts.

https://gofile.io/d/PGQjUy

(let me know if the link becomes dead)

Here's the result of extracting frame #3 using this command: `ffmpeg -i sample-yuv420p-video.mkv -vf "select=eq(n,3)" "PNG_defaultrange_defaultfmt_%%03d.png"`

[image: banding artifacts are present]

Here's all the other parameter combinations I tried, the banding artifacts change slightly but never go away:

```
ffmpeg -i sample-yuv420p-video.mkv -vf "select=eq(n\,3)" "PNG_defaultrange_defaultfmt_%%03d.png"
ffmpeg -i sample-yuv420p-video.mkv -vf "select=eq(n\,3)" -pix_fmt rgb24 "PNG_defaultrange_rgb24_%%03d.png"
ffmpeg -i sample-yuv420p-video.mkv -vf "select=eq(n\,3)" -pix_fmt rgb48be "PNG_defaultrange_rgb48be_%%03d.png"
ffmpeg -i sample-yuv420p-video.mkv -vf "select=eq(n\,3)" -sws_flags +accurate_rnd+full_chroma_int "PNG_full_defaultfmt_%%03d.png"
ffmpeg -i sample-yuv420p-video.mkv -vf "select=eq(n\,3)" -sws_flags +accurate_rnd+full_chroma_int -pix_fmt rgb24 "PNG_full_rgb24_%%03d.png"
ffmpeg -i sample-yuv420p-video.mkv -vf "select=eq(n\,3)" -sws_flags +accurate_rnd+full_chroma_int -pix_fmt rgb48be "PNG_full_rgb48be_%%03d.png"
ffmpeg -i sample-yuv420p-video.mkv -vf "select=eq(n\,3)" -src_range 0 -dst_range 0 -sws_flags +accurate_rnd+full_chroma_int -pix_fmt rgb48be "PNG_full2_rgb48be_%%03d.png"
ffmpeg -i sample-yuv420p-video.mkv -vf "select=eq(n\,3)" -src_range 1 -dst_range 0 -sws_flags +accurate_rnd+full_chroma_int -pix_fmt rgb48be "PNG_full3_rgb48be_%%03d.png"
ffmpeg -i sample-yuv420p-video.mkv -vf "select=eq(n\,3)" -src_range 0 -dst_range 1 -sws_flags +accurate_rnd+full_chroma_int -pix_fmt rgb48be "PNG_full4_rgb48be_%%03d.png"
ffmpeg -i sample-yuv420p-video.mkv -vf "select=eq(n\,3)" -src_range 1 -dst_range 1 -sws_flags +accurate_rnd+full_chroma_int -pix_fmt rgb48be "PNG_full5_rgb48be_%%03d.png"
```

This is (I hope) merely a case of bad luck with the combinations of parameters I tried. In short, is there any parameter combination that would yield a lossless PNG output?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I edited the question. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: I made VLC display the video without rescaling (Video, uncheck Always Fit Window; Video, Zoom, 1:1 Orignal). I made it play in slow-mo (Playback, Speed, …). This way I could see every frame 1:1. It seems the artifacts *are* there. My guess is you didn't see them because rescaling in VLC smooths them.

Comment: This command runs VLC with settings I described above: `vlc --no-autoscale --zoom 1 --rate 0.1 sample-yuv420p-video.mkv` (at least in Linux).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Ok I can confirm... Which means that VLC has a hidden filter that ONLY engages if the view is ever so slightly rescaled to fit the window? This isn't even the necessary bilinear or bicubic filter, this is a full-blown high-quality debanding filter we are talking about, the difference is huge, drastically altering the viewed content to the user. Where is the documentation for this? Could you link me to the relevant page? I am so bummed right now for having been deceived by VLC to this degree.

Comment: Currently I don't know the documentation, I don't know the relevant page.

Answer (score 0):

Why?
The reason is sample: to extract lossless image from video you should use as source RAW video.

In any other format you have one or another compression scheme. And you do not see it because video is moving picture, you have 24,25,30 FPS and this smooth (mitigate) the effect of compression (small defects, digital noise and so on).